# Call the content of a page in AJAX in Wordpress

Tags: pages, jquery, ajax

Out of Wordpress, I've made a simple index page wich call the content of 10 other pages thanks to AJAX. Now I need to put this into Wordpress and the AJAX calls don't work at all.

I have created the homepage and 10 other pages. When the user arrives on my website, the homepage has a menu. Each item of this menu has a link with the HREF relative to 1 of the 10  pages (thanks to get_permalink( page_id );). My script get the value of the HREF and try to load the content of the page. I worked out of Wordpress but it doesn't inside of Wordpress.

Here is the menu :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 41 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">0</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">La coparentalité</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 43 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">1</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">N’obligez pas votre enfant à faire un choix</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 45 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">2</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Optez pour un discours positif</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 49 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">3</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Épargnez les détails à votre enfant</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 51 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">4</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Ne faites pas de votre enfant votre messager</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 53 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">5</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Détachez-vous de votre ex-conjoint</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 55 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">6</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Fixez des limites et des attentes pour vos enfants</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 57 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">7</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Restez ouvert à la communication</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 59 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">8</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Devenez adulte et responsable</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 61 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">9</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Mettez votre enfant en confiance et en sécurité</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 63 ); ?>" data-parallax><span class="accessibility">Règle #</span><span class="number">10</span><span class="accessibility"> -</span><span class="rule-label">Apprenez à rebondir !</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

In function.php, I have that :

```
/************************************************************************/
/*  JS
/************************************************************************/

function load_my_scripts() {

    //Include one of my custom javascript files
    wp_register_script('scrollTo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js', array('jquery'), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'), true );
    wp_register_script('seo-parallax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.seo-parallax.js', array('jquery'), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/jquery.seo-parallax.js'), true );
    wp_register_script('myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/scripts.js'), true );

    wp_enqueue_script('scrollTo');
    wp_enqueue_script('seo-parallax');
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');
```

In jquery.seo-parallax, I have that :

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.SEOParallax = function() {
        var container_id = "content"; // the id of the container (must be the same on each page)
        var container = $("#"+container_id); // the container where the content will be put in
        var pages = $("a[data-parallax]"); // every content that should be injected
        var number = 0;
        // console.log(number);
        $(container).html("");
        pages.each(function(page){
            var page = $(this);

            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            console.log(url);
            // Remove the current content
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                // console.log(url);
                var code = $(data);
                code.each(function() {
                    if($(this).attr("id") == container_id){
                        subcontainer = $("<span id='rule-photo-"+number+"-anchor' class='rule-anchor'></span>")
                        $(subcontainer).appendTo($(container));
                        $($(this).html()).insertAfter($(subcontainer));
                        $(page).attr("href", "#rule-photo-"+number+"-anchor");
                        number += 1;

                    } 
                })
            });
        });
            // wrap the content and include it in the page

        // end
  };
})( jQuery );
```

In scripts.js, I have that :

```
;( function($) {
    $( "body" ).SEOParallax();

    $( "body" ).delegate( "a", "click", function() {
        $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
            scrollTop: $( $( this ).attr( "href" ) ).offset().top
        }, 1200 );
        return false;
    } );
} )( jQuery || {} );
```

So normally, when the page is loaded, the seo-parallax script take the 11 links that are in the navigation, empty #content of the current page and add the content in #content of each page. On chrome, the content is not in the good order. Normally y has to place the content is this order : 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10. But instead, it's randomly placed (example : 1-4-0-9-6-10-2-5-8-3-7).

**UPDATE :**
I've called `<?php var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_query']) ?>` juste before `<?php get_footer(); ?>`, here what I have :

```
object(WP_Query)#23 (47) { ["query_vars"]=> array(55) { ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> int(0) ["p"]=> string(2) "41" ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> string(2) "41" ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["comments_popup"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(false) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["post_type"]=> string(0) "" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(10) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#43 (2) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" } ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#42 (2) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL } ["post_count"]=> int(1) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(true) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_comments_popup"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(true) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false) ["query_vars_hash"]=> string(32) "8f15f3752a526b936a323e2a33ace1e5" ["query_vars_changed"]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["query"]=> array(0) { } ["request"]=> string(143) "SELECT wp_4_posts.* FROM wp_4_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_4_posts.ID = 41 AND wp_4_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_4_posts.post_date DESC " ["posts"]=> &array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#62 (25) { ["ID"]=> int(41) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "7" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(38) "La coparentalité, comment ça marche?" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(34) "la-coparentalite-comment-ca-marche" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(43) "http://miniguide.wp.2houses.com/?page_id=41" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["ancestors"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } ["post"]=> object(stdClass)#62 (25) { ["ID"]=> int(41) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "7" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(38) "La coparentalité, comment ça marche?" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(34) "la-coparentalite-comment-ca-marche" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(43) "http://miniguide.wp.2houses.com/?page_id=41" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["ancestors"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["queried_object"]=> object(stdClass)#62 (25) { ["ID"]=> int(41) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "7" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 11:06:49" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(38) "La coparentalité, comment ça marche?" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(34) "la-coparentalite-comment-ca-marche" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-03-20 14:29:31" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(43) "http://miniguide.wp.2houses.com/?page_id=41" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["ancestors"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["queried_object_id"]=> int(41) }
```

Where is the problem ? 
Thanks you

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91612/385) on how loading should be done. Take a deep look at the `filemtime()` part and the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. Then change this in your code, test it again and report back/update the question.

Comment: Please wrap that dump in `<pre>` tags before posting it. This is not readable. `echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars( var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_query'], true ) ).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 3):

I already mentioned in the comments, that [there're preferred ways to load your scripts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91612/385). The most important is to define the dependencies and the using the proper hooks.

The following part won't work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").SEOParallax();

    $("body").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
        }, 1200);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The [WordPress Javascript Coding Standards by Tom McFarlin](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#JavaScript) show you the right way to do it - avoiding the need for the no conflict mode:

```
;( function ($) {
    // ...
} ( jQuery ) );
```

This is a self invoking —and immediately executing— function, injecting `jQuery` as first argument, which gets named `$` *inside* the scope of the function itself. Now you can safely use `$` instead of `jQuery`.

So your script should look like this:

```
;( function($) {
    $( "body" ).SEOParallax();

    $( "body" ).delegate( "a", "click", function() {
        $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
            scrollTop: $( $( this ).attr( "href" ) ).offset().top
        }, 1200 );
        return false;
    } );
} )( jQuery || {} );
```

I should as well note that you shouldn't use `.delegate()` anymore. Quote from jQuery:

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the alternative `.on()` method may be used in place of `.delegate()`"

but that's part of another discussion better moved over to StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Kaiser ! I've done everything you said, but still the same problem. But I've found something : when I try to go on one of the other 1à pages, I have a "Page not found" !!! The permalinks structure is /%postname%/ . When I change the permalinks structure to default (page ID), it works well :s ! Have you got an idea ?

Comment: @CédricCharles Yes: Flush your permalinks again (visit Settings > Permalink > Update). Anyway: 404s are another topic. Please go and update your question with what your code looks like, your error/var_dump/debug and console messages.

Comment: I've update the permalinks, but still doesn't work... Anyway, with the post_ID structure, I still have a problem. The 11 pages are added to my page in a random order. Sometimes it's the good one (0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10), sometimes not (random, for example : (1-8-2-4-0-5-7-10-3-6-9)  :s !

Comment: @CédricCharles **Please go back and update your question with _all your code_**. This is the _third_ problem you're bringing to the table... :/

Comment: I've updated my code :)

Comment: @CédricCharles Could you please try it without the CDN version of jQuery (from Google)? And show us a dump of the `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` object.

Comment: Done ! Update in the original post ! Thank you very much Kaiser

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using [`djax`](https://github.com/beezee/djax), which is dynamic `pjax` (and [`pjax`](http://pjax.heroku.com/) being ajax using pushState).

`pjax` (and by extension `djax`) allows you to set a container on the page that exists in all other pages, for example a `<div id="content">`. You simply add a class to it that you also define in the JavaScript of the plugin. For example: `<div id="content" class="dynamic">`.

This plugin now attempts to load the HTML of the requested URL, looks for the element with the `dynamic` class and replaces the current page's contents of that element with the fetched result.

`djax` was a `pjax`-modification specifically designed for WordPress, and I'm successfully using it on http://www.tjoonz.com (if you want to see a working example).